# 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

i have written a javascript code to compare 2dates from 2 textboxes

```
     function CompareDates() {
            var fdate = document.getElementById('txtFromDate');
            var edate = document.getElementById('txtToDate');
            var FromDate = fdate.value.split('/');
            var EndDate = edate.value.split('/');
            var val = 'false';

            if (parseInt(FromDate[2]) < parseInt(EndDate[2])) {
                val = 'true';
                return true;
            }
            else if (parseInt(FromDate[2]) == parseInt(EndDate[2])) {
                if (parseInt(FromDate[0]) < parseInt(EndDate[0])) {
                    val = 'true';
                    return true;
                }
                else if (parseInt(FromDate[0]) == parseInt(EndDate[0])) {
                    if (parseInt(FromDate[1]) <= parseInt(EndDate[1])) {
                        val = 'true';
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (val == "false") {
                alert("FromDate Always Less Than ToDate");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

and html code is

```
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server" Width="150px" />
     <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender CssClass="MyCalendar" runat="server"
                                   ID="ceFromDate"
                                   TargetControlID="txtFromDate"
                                   Format="dd/MM/yyyy" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" runat="server" Width="150px" />
    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender CssClass="MyCalendar" runat="server" 
                                  ID="ceToDAte"
                                  TargetControlID="txtToDate"
                                  Format="dd/MM/yyyy" />

     <asp:Button ID="btnGenerate" runat="server" CssClass="button"
                 Text="Generate" OnClientClick="if(!CompareDates()) return false;" 
                 OnClick="btnGenerate_Click" />
```

the problem is that the page is running well in chrome but when i run my application in IE it throw an error

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value'
>   of undefined or null reference

please help me to overcome from this problem.

Comment: What version of "IE"? Have you tried to debug it with the developer tools?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is here:

```
    var fdate = document.getElementById('txtFromDate');
    var edate = document.getElementById('txtToDate');
```

The problem is that `txtFromDate` and `txtToDate` are the server name of controls, not the client name (look the source of page from the browser).

Try this:

```
    var fdate = document.getElementById('<%=txtFromDate.ClientID%>');
    var edate = document.getElementById('<%=txtToDate.ClientID%>');
```

Answer (score 2):

If your javascript is located in an external JS file (which it should), the posted solutions will not work.  But you could give the text fields a unique class name and modify your code as such:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server" Width="150px" CssClass="txtFromDate" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" runat="server" Width="150px" CssClass="txtToDate" />
```

and your javascript:

```
var fdate = document.getElementsByClassName('txtFromDate')[0];
var edate = document.getElementsByClassName('txtToDate')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
 document.getElementById('<%=txtFromDate.ClientID %>')
```

Change your code like following:

```
function CompareDates() {
    var fdate = document.getElementById('<%=txtFromDate.ClientID %>');
    var edate = document.getElementById('<%=txtFromDate.ClientID %>');
    var FromDate = fdate.value.split('/');
    var EndDate = edate.value.split('/');
    var val = 'false';

    if (parseInt(FromDate[2]) < parseInt(EndDate[2])) {
        val = 'true';
        return true;
    }
    else if (parseInt(FromDate[2]) == parseInt(EndDate[2])) {
        if (parseInt(FromDate[0]) < parseInt(EndDate[0])) {
            val = 'true';
            return true;
        }
        else if (parseInt(FromDate[0]) == parseInt(EndDate[0])) {
            if (parseInt(FromDate[1]) <= parseInt(EndDate[1])) {
                val = 'true';
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (val == "false") {
        alert("FromDate Always Less Than ToDate");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `#` for your id reference.
Change from:

```
var fdate = document.getElementById('txtFromDate');
```

to:

```
var fdate = document.getElementById('#txtFromDate');
```

I was wrong about the above statements.
I was able to fix the same error in my jquery code where I was missing the `#`.  `getElementById` does not need this special character.