# How to stubbornly keep an old JavaScript event handler in a webform page ported to ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, event-handling, porting

Considering a single line of markup in an .ASPX file as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpdownPayPlan" runat="server" onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('txtPayAmount').value = document.getElementById('drpdownPayPlan').value.replace(',', '');">
```

May I keep my embedded JavaScript handler code and how? I understand there are lots of other issues when porting a WebForms application to ASP.NET MVC, but I'd like to keep it simple and just focus on this one line. Currently, the error I get on this line is:

> Unhandled exception at line 410, column 115 in http://localhost:3835/Policy/QuotePayments?QN=XYZ-1234567&PN=ABCDEFGHIJ&AC=123456789
>
> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value'
>   of undefined or null reference

When rendered, the source code actually reads as follows on line 410 (I understand the reason for mangled names):

```
    <select name="ctl00$MainContent$drpdownPayPlan" id="MainContent_drpdownPayPlan" onchange="javascript: document.getElementById(&#39;txtPayAmount&#39;).value = document.getElementById(&#39;drpdownPayPlan&#39;).value.replace(&#39;,&#39;, &#39;&#39;);">
```

So, with all due respect--without giving me a sermon on how to properly port a WebForms project to MVC (sorry for sounding like a rebellious and uncooperative teenager!)--how can I resolve the issue I'm having with this one line of markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `0x800a138f` error in ASPX page often occurs when trying to assign server-side control name (which doesn't exist in client-side due to default server control behavior assigning `AutoID`) instead of client-side name, therefore `document.getElementById('drpdownPayPlan')` returns `undefined`.

There are 2 ways to resolve it:

1. Assign `ClientIDMode="Static"` to every server control involved (I assumed that `txtPayAmount` is a `TextBox` server control, if you're using literal input text box leave `txtPayAmount` as is).

   ```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtPayAmount" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
   <asp:DropDownList ID="drpdownPayPlan" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('txtPayAmount').value = document.getElementById('drpdownPayPlan').value.replace(',', '');">
   ```

   NB: The `ClientIDMode` attribute available in .NET version 4.0 and later.
2. Use `<%= drpdownPayPlan.ClientID %>` to refer client-side ID while keeping control IDs in `AutoID` state (again I assumed `txtPayAmount` is a `TextBox` control here, leave it if `txtPayAmount` is a literal text box).

   ```
   <asp:DropDownList ID="drpdownPayPlan" runat="server" onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('<%= txtPayAmount.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%= drpdownPayPlan.ClientID %>').value.replace(',', '');">
   ```

Note that I recommend you to separate the JS part from server control in a function and call the function name as given below:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpdownPayPlan" runat="server" onchange="changePayAmount();">

<script type="text/javascript">
function changePayAmount() {
    document.getElementById('<%= txtPayAmount.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%= drpdownPayPlan.ClientID %>').value.replace(',', '');
}
</script>
```

PS: In MVC context, the `id` for every HTML helper element can be easily defined in HTML attributes part like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PayPlan, Model.PayPlanList as SelectList, new { id = "drpdownPayPlan" })
```

Similar issues:

[0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457558/0x800a138f-javascript-runtime-error-unable-to-get-property-value-of-undefin)

[JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968078/javascript-runtime-error-unable-to-get-property-value-of-undefined-or-null-re)

Comment: Thank you, @Tetsuya-Yamamoto! Your first option worked! I had tried the second option myself prior to posting the question because that's all I knew, but it would not change the outcome. However, like you suggested, assigning ClientIDMode="Static" to every server control involved did fix my issue! I set that attribute both on to my txtPayAmount control tag and also drpdownPayPlan. Voilà! Domo arigato gozaimasu!